# Playing video on Raspberry PI 3B with Python 3.7

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, pyglet

How can I play a video on Raspberry Pi 3b with Python 3.7? I have tried the following code, this works on desktop but on pi it gives me a cryptic "Bus Error" problem. Tried to use try catch block to print more information but it did not print anything

```
import pyglet
import traceback

pyglet.have_avbin = True
pyglet.options['search_local_libs'] = True
vidPath = "sample1.mp4"
exc_obj=None
window = pyglet.window.Window(width=500, height=500)

player = pyglet.media.Player()

player.volume = 0
source = pyglet.media.StreamingSource()
try:
    mediaLoad = pyglet.media.load(vidPath)


    player.queue(mediaLoad)

    player.play()
except Exception as exc:
     tb = traceback.TracebackException.from_exception(exc)
     print(''.join(tb.stack.format()))



@window.event
def on_draw():
    if player.source and player.source.video_format:
        player.get_texture().blit(0, 0)


pyglet.app.run()
```

Is there any other library that can be used to achieve the same or any other way to fix this error.
I can change my hardware to 3b+ or 4 if needed.

Comment: You should include the error traceback message. Could you be more specific?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: do you have problem to run python script which doesn't use `pyglet` or doesn't try to play video ?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not print any information in the except block.
Only error I get is "Bus Error", Script runs , creates a window but fails thereafter.